# Issues with Loop -- Cannot Move Past First Iteration

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy data from a series of sheets (dynamically created based on user preferences) into a master sheet located at the end. However, after the first loop, Excel runs into an object oriented error (1004).

```
Dim MacroWorkbook As Workbook
Set MacroWorkbook = Thisworkbook

Dim NumSheets As Integer
Dim DataSheets As Integer
Dim LCounter As Single

'Count the number of sheets
NumSheets = MacroWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
'Count the number of sheets minus the mastersheet (located at the end). 
DataSheets = NumSheets - 1

'As long as the counter is less than the number of total sheets (i.e. master sheet)
Do While LCounter < NumSheets
    LCounter = LCounter + 1
    MacroWorkbook.Sheets(LCounter).Range(Range("A2"), Range("AU5001")).Copy
    MacroWorkbook.Sheets(NumSheets).Range("A1").End(xlDown).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Loop
```

1) Why can't Excel execute on the second loop?

2) Does the error have to do with using Copy/Paste? Is there a more efficient/less clunky way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because you need to add sheet references to all ranges, but your code would appear to be overwriting each time you paste? And your Do line should refer to DataSheets rather than NumSheets I think.

```
Dim MacroWorkbook As Workbook
Set MacroWorkbook = ThisWorkbook

Dim NumSheets As Integer
Dim DataSheets As Integer
Dim LCounter As Single

'Count the number of sheets
NumSheets = MacroWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
'Count the number of sheets minus the mastersheet (located at the end).
DataSheets = NumSheets - 1

'As long as the counter is less than the number of total sheets (i.e. master sheet)
Do While LCounter < NumSheets
    LCounter = LCounter + 1
    With MacroWorkbook
        .Sheets(LCounter).Range(.Sheets(LCounter).Range("A2"), .Sheets(LCounter).Range("AU5000")).Copy
        .Sheets(NumSheets).Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End With
Loop
```

Comment: You're right that the data overwrites itself. That was just some placeholder code, it's been updated in the OP. You're code works, though.